# Reset "Search" in Notepad

Tags: c#, loops, search, reset

I'm currently using the following code to allow the user to "Search" through the text they've written and highlight a particular word/phrase..

```
int len = this.txtPad.TextLength;
            int index = 0;
            int lastIndex = this.txtPad.Text.LastIndexOf(this.textBox1.Text);

        while (index < lastIndex)
        {
            this.txtPad.Find(this.textBox1.Text, index, len, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            this.txtPad.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
            index = this.txtPad.Text.IndexOf(this.textBox1.Text, index) + 1;
        }
```

It works fine by highlighting the words they enter in the textbox yellow. However, when i click a "Close" button, I want the text to no longer be highlighted yellow and go back to its previous colour.

I think this is really easy, but I just can't get my head around it. I am only a few classes in to the C# class at school so I apoligise if this is incredibly easy and I am being stupid.

I tried changing "This.txtPad.SelectionBackColor" to a different colour but it only changed one out of many search results. It just hit me that a **loop** might be the right way to go about this?

Thanks in advance! This is just to try teach myself a few things outside of class.

(the search code is not my original code so if we're supposed to give credit on here then thanks to whoever wrote it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select all text.
2. Set the selection color to the default color.

Or, remember the selections that you have made in a list. Then you can later run through that list and reset the formatting just for those places.

Or, remember the rich text string before formatting and restore the string later.